# Orbeon Form Builder - physical placement of form elements

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible to control the formatting/physical placement of the form elements on the form? I understand the current layout is grid-based. I am wondering if it is possible to use Form Builder to build a form that exactly (or at least closely) matches our sales lead generation paper form.

Thanks
GP

Answer (score 0):

Form Builder only supports a grid-based layout. If the layout you have in mind is completely different, then you could write the XForms "by hand". Doing so, you can fully control the layout of the form fields by writing your own HTML.